# wilcoxon test using data stratification

Tags: r

I have a really basic problem. I have the concentrations of one chemical stored in one column and the gender of the study participant in a second column. 
What is the code to do the wilcoxon test to see if there is a difference between the concentrations found in boys and the concentrations found in girls? Some explanation of the code would also be useful for me to understand how it works. Thanks!

I got this code for the ANOVA test to work which is also fine. Can anyone tell me if it does the thing that I need?

```
av <- aov(UC_MEHP ~ BQF05C1, data=data)
av
summary(av)
```

the output looks like this

```
> av <- aov(UC_MEHP ~ BQF05C1, data=data)
> av
Call:
   aov(formula = UC_MEHP ~ BQF05C1, data = data)

Terms:
                  BQF05C1 Residuals
Sum of Squares     0.3445 2917.4564
Deg. of Freedom         1       151

Residual standard error: 4.395555
Estimated effects may be unbalanced
21 observations deleted due to missingness
> summary(av)
             Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)
BQF05C1       1    0.3   0.344   0.018  0.894
Residuals   151 2917.5  19.321               
21 observations deleted due to missingness
```

I'm sorry, I know it's not a very advanced question...

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I tried with the stratified function (stratified(df, group, size, select = NULL, seed = NULL, ...)), but I don't understand the syntax of the function, so I didn't get it to work. Also, I'm not sure if this function does what I need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From `?wilcox.test`:

> ## S3 method for class 'formula'
>        wilcox.test(formula, data, subset, na.action, ...)
>   ...
>   formula: a formula of the form ‘lhs ~ rhs’ where ‘lhs’ is a numeric
>             variable giving the data values and ‘rhs’ a factor with two
>             levels giving the corresponding groups.

So `wilcox.test(UC_MEHP ~ BQF05C1, data=data)` should work (assuming that `BQF05C1` is the column specifying gender and `UC_MEHP` is the concentration).